# Do registration of corporate domain and individual domain differ?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name

Is there such a thing as business domain registration that differs from individual domain registration?

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of like asking if there's a "business car" that differs from a "personal use car". There are many different domain registrars and they have all kinds of different plans and product targeting.

[CSC](https://www.cscglobal.com/global/web/csc/domains-and-trademarks.html) for example, offers a variety of domain name registration services aimed at the needs of large companies. So does [MarkMonitor](https://www.cscglobal.com/global/web/csc/domains-and-trademarks.html). But many companies also just use basic registration from companies like GoDaddy and NSI.